# Milliseconds until midnight (local time) in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, time

I'm am writing an iOS app and I need to know the (whole) number of milliseconds until midnight (that is, 12:00:00.000 the next day) in the user's local time using Swift.

The application is in an expression like this:

```
let milliseconds_until_midnight : Int;

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(milliseconds_until_midnight)) {

  //do_something
}
```

How can we do this? Addendum: the type must be Int, as UInt64 is not accepted in this particular situation.

Comment: I have tried to do this myself first. The datetime functionality in Swift is more opaque than in Java or other languages I know. I don't see why this was downvoted. As the two (for now) incorrect answers below demonstrate, this isn't trivial.

Comment: what is wrong in my answer?

Comment: Nothing! It is excellent. I was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Is it really still believed that this question is too broad?

Comment: @el-tomato Why is this too broad?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use Calendar method `nextDate(after:)` to get the start of the next day, use Date method `timeIntervalSince(date:)` to find out the number of seconds until the next day and return it multiplied it by 1000:

```
extension Date {
    var startOfNextDay: Date {
        return Calendar.current.nextDate(after: self, matching: DateComponents(hour: 0, minute: 0), matchingPolicy: .nextTimePreservingSmallerComponents)!
    }
    var millisecondsUntilTheNextDay: TimeInterval {
        return startOfNextDay.timeIntervalSince(self) * 1000
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let milliseconds = UInt64(Date().millisecondsUntilTheNextDay)   // 7731021
```

Comment: This looks like an excellent answer to me. It answers the OPs question directly and specifically.  (voted.) Who downvoted it and why?

Comment: This answer provides a decimal value. If you want an integer value, simply cast it to an `Int` or `Int64`

Comment: The OP didn't say what numeric type he was expecting it. Note that "cast" it is not possible OP needs to initialize an Integer in coercion.

Comment: Understood about the OP not specifying a type. The phrase "number milliseconds sort of loosely *implies* an integral count, which is why I suggested it. And yes, I was sloppy using the term "cast" since Swift doesn't really allow casts among scalar types the way we're used to thinking of them. Type Coercion is more accurate term.

Comment: @Duncan, Leo: A Happy New Year to you and everyone!

Comment: You probably want `.nextTimePreservingSmallerComponents`. If you use `previous`, you may get the wrong answer if the following day has no midnight, such as when DST ended in the Brazil/East time zone on 2017-10-15.

Comment: I didn't downvote! For my particular application (added after this answer was posted), I had to coerce to Int, not UInt64. XCode's red-box explanation of why was very cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to count down number of seconds before midnight:

```
extension  Date{
    // code to get phone's time zone
    var localTimeZoneName: String { return TimeZone.current.identifier }

    var numberOfMilliSecondsUntilMidnight: TimeInterval?{
        let todayDate = self
        let tomorrowDate = todayDate.tomorrowAtMidnight
        return tomorrowDate.timeIntervalSince(self) * 1000

    }
    // local time. beginning tomorrow at 12 AM
    var tomorrowAtMidnight: Date{
        var cal = Calendar.current
        cal.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        let today =  cal.startOfDay(for: self)
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: today)!
    }
}
```

To call for anyone who is new to swift:

```
print(Date().numberOfMilliSecondsUntilMidnight)
```

I am pretty sure it works because I had to write a custom date class for a due date system.

Comment: Your numberOfMilliSecondsUntilMidnight have only a resolution of seconds. Also much of your code seems to be unrelated to this particular question.

Comment: The question asks for the *"number of milliseconds until midnight"* – Of course you can compute the number of seconds and multiply that by 1000, but that is not the best possible precision.

Comment: You called your method numberOfMilliSecondsUntilMidnight but you are returning the  number of seconds.